# Woking with node.js and mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

// So I am using mysql with node and express framework and the first time I created a test example everything worked fine. But then I tried to create a second project and now the routing seems to not being read.

And the respond back I get is:

```
  [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
  [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
  Server started on port 8000
  mysql connected...
```

//I am also supposed to get the result back:

OkPackege{...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    }

```
//But I am not getting it. Any Ideas...? thanks.
```

The scrips that i have are as follow:

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host      : 'localhost',
  user      : 'root',
  password  : 'LEoking1987'
  //database  : 'nodesql'
});

db.connect((err) => {
  if(err){
      throw err;
  }
  console.log('mysql connected...');
});

const app = express();

// Creates satabase if it does not exist yet.
app.get('/createdb',(req,res) => {
    let sql = 'CREATE DATABASE nodesql';
    db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
      if(err) throw err;
      console.log(result);
      res.send('Database created...');
    });
});

app.listen('8000',()=>{
  console.log('Server started on port 8000');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add debug: true in your mysql connection params like

```
  mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'LEoking1987'
  database: 'nodesql'
  debug: true,     
})
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer what exactly means? and is it the right answer for this question?

Comment: Also I am new to node so I was not clear that I had to go to localhost/8000/createdb

Comment: OkPackege{... ... ... ... } ... etc are debug messages only show when debug true and LeoR  said "//But I am not getting it. Any Ideas...? thanks. ". so i think answer is correct and well explained (now not before) @abdulbarik